# bash programming - best practice setting up variables within a loop or not

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following logic in my bash/shell script. Where essentially, I'm trying to pass one argument manually and then passing in other values from a hidden file, like so:

```
if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
   echo "./tstscript.sh <IDNUM>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

MYKEY=/dev/scripts/.mykey

if [ -f "$MYKEY" ]
then
IFS=';'
declare -a arr=($(< $MYKEY))
# DECLARE VARIABLES
HOSTNM=localhost
PORT=5432
PSQL_HOME=/bin
IDNUM=$1
DBU1=${arr[0]}

export HOSTNM PORT PSQL_HOME IDNUM DBU1 DBU2
$PSQL_HOME/psql -h $HOSTNM -p $PORT -U $DBU1 -v v1=$IDNUM -f t1.sql postgres

else
    echo "Mykey not found"
fi
rt_code=?
exit 1
```

Am I declaring my variables in the right place? Should it be declaring within my if statement?

Comment: I don't see a loop. I just see an `if` statement.

Comment: Questions about programming style are off-topic here, they're too opinion-based.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is where you can ask for help with improving the quality of your code, rather than fixing bugs.

Comment: This question should better be asked in code-review (beta)

Comment: Don't read file contents into an array like that. Use `read`. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your variables are redundant. `psql` already has a few well-known environment variables it will use if you don't specify various parameters on the command line. The others are just hard-coded, so it's not really important to define them. It really doesn't matter much where you define them, as long as you define them before they are used, since this isn't a very large script. It's a good sign that you've outgrown shell script and are ready for a more robust programming language when you start worrying about the design of the shell script.

```
if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
   echo "./tstscript.sh <IDNUM>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

MYKEY=/dev/scripts/.mykey

if ! [ -f "$MYKEY" ]; then
    echo "Mykey not found"
    exit 1
fi

# You only use the first word/line of the file,
# so this should be sufficient.
IFS=";" read -a arr < "$MYKEY"

export PGHOST=localhost
export PGPORT=5432
export PGUSER=${arr[0]}

: ${PSQL_HOME:=/bin}

"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -v v1="$1" -f t1.sql postgres
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you doing with here? : `${PSQL_HOME:=/bin`  Is that so you can use the double quotes in the next line?

Comment: I forgot I wrote it that way. Basically, it sets the value of `PSQL_HOME` to `/bin`, but only if it doesn't already have a non-null value. This way, `./tstscript.sh 3` would use `/bin/psql`, but `PSQL_HOME=/usr/bin ./tstscript.sh 3` would use `/usr/bin/psql`. (Which is a one-time use shortcut for `export PSQL_HOME=/usr/bin; ./tstscript.sh3`.) In other words, it's a way of setting a default value for an environment variable if it isn't set by the caller.

Comment: I'm seeing an `IFS: command not found` although the script still worked and the keyfile was read. Do I have to put a path to this?

Comment: The error surprises me, but the code is wrong. As written, it's interpreted as a standalone statement setting `IFS` to the empty string; the semicolon is treated as a statement terminator. However, if the script worked properly (what does `.mykey` look like, anyway?), you might be able to just drop the custom setting for `IFS` in the `read` command.

Comment: The .mykey is basically this `abc#123!;abc#456!;abc#789!` where they values I am after are `;` separated. Do you mean just drop `IFS` altogether?

Comment: No, it looks like you should need it. See my edit to the answer; the semicolon just needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When you fill /dev/scripts/.mykey with lines in the form key=value, you can source that file.

```
$ cat /dev/scripts/.mykey
DBU1=noober
FIELD2="String with space"
echo "Keep it clean, do not use commands like this echo in the file"
```

In your script you can activate the settings by sourcing the file

```
if [ -f "${MYKEY}" ]; then
   . "${MYKEY}"
   # Continue without an array, DBU1 and FIELD2 are set.
```